# Looking for a special Death Note chapter

Tags: death-note

I read Death Note for the first time about 10 years ago. I remember of a special chapter at the end, which I was not able to find, even in the manga (I own them all - or I think I do):

> Some of that chapter takes place in the Deathgod's world. After Light's death, we see him atone for every single name he wrote in his Death Note. After a while, he tells Ryuk the exact number of people he's killed with his Death Note. Then, he asks Ryuk to bring bring to the Deathgod's King: his world has gone to waste and Light would like to make it prosper once more. The chapter end with Ryuk being impressed once more of Light's tenacity and mental strength.

**Answer:**

Anki Sharma's answer is correct. The chapter I was looking for is indeed fanbase, I found a youtube [link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue8fM2FBL_A&feature=youtu.be).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the rumored [alternate ending](http://deathnotefanon.wikia.com/wiki/Alternative_ending) of Death Note?

From [deathnotefanon.wikia.com](http://deathnotefanon.wikia.com/wiki/Alternative_ending):

> The Death Note alternative ending is a possible ending to show
>   something else that might have happened to Light Yagami after his
>   death. It is unknown if the ending is real or fake. There is a lack of
>   evidence to prove the ending to be real. It has really only been seen
>   on the Internet and there are mainly English versions of the ending
>   circulating, but it has become popular in the Death Note fandom.
>
> Due to the fact that there is no proof, it’s left to fans to decide
>   for themselves. **The ending only exists in manga form**; there is no
>   anime adaptation for the ending.

But in this ending Light decides to die in old age and tell Ryuk to kill him. After his death he appears in the Shinigami Realm and starts dying again and again in the ways his victims died. Then Light tells Ryuk to take him to their king, so that he can make deal with him. He even tells that he will kill their kind if he doesn't agree. But the end just shows the start of their journey, there's no interaction with the king.